# update-grub does not detect linux partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub

I had windows and debian installed alongside on the same SSD and working seamlessly. During my experiments I played with Windows installation from USB and (of course) it ended up with grub rescue mode.

I'm not certain, but it is possible that in frenzy I did:

```
grub-install /dev/sda6 # (where /dev/sda6 is my root linux partition)
```

because now, after some playing in terminal:

```
update-grub
```

detects only Windows parition which resides on /dev/sda1.
During my search I found this [page](https://josephhall.org/grub_install_hda1.html)
and I would like to ask whether it is safe to zero out MBR as it is described in the link.
I mean, (since I don't know when was the linked post written) are those numbers from commands:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hda bs=446 count=1
# and
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hda1 bs=512 count=1
```

still correct? I wouldn't like to make things worse than they already are...

Comment: You have a really old example. They changed from hda to sda years ago. And all those only apply if BIOS/MBR not newer UEFI install. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of existance of Boot-Repair. Here's my report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Zqjcv65gs9/ 
I'm waiting for your suggestions...

Comment: Best to never erase a PBR - partition boot sector. And Windows has essential boot info in its PBR or sda1. So do not erase that. You can just run the suggested fix to see if then grub works.

Comment: OK. I ran the fix but it didn't help. Here's the report:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/md95yRDT2x/
I guess the crucial lines are those ones: 
"=================== linux-generic purge cancelled
Please enable a repository containing the [linux-generic] packages in the software sources of Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) (sda6). Then try again."

Comment: Not familiar with Debian updates. But it looks like grub updated. Perhaps Boot-Repair is looking for the Ubuntu kernel linux-generic and that is not how Debian names kernel?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance oldfred. Sorry for bothering you but do you have any hints what to do now?

Comment: Does grub menu appear & can you choose to boot one of the entries?

Comment: Yes, grub menu appears and I can choose Windows. Windows works ok.

Comment: Can you boot recovery mode or older kernel?

Comment: No. My grub menu contains only one entry i.e. the one that loads Windows.

Comment: I think you need to do a total reinstall of grub as you seem to have several odd settings. You have grldr which uses very old grub4dos  & some zen files. Use Advanced mode in Boot-Repair and make sure Internet is working.

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested but again I got an error: "Please enable a repository containing the [linux-generic] packages in the software source of Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) (sda6). Then try again.

Comment: I found this: https://www.supergrubdisk.org . I'm going to give it a try...

Comment: I followed the manual provided here: https://www.supergrubdisk.org/wizard-restore-grub-with-rescatux/ but this tool does not work either. Processes of restoration of grub and rebuilding the menu end with 'success' messages, but I still have only Windows entry in grub menu... Is there any hope for me?

Comment: I do not know Debian well enough to know what repository you are missing. It should all be standard in your /etc/apt/sources.list. Did you delete  anything there. You may be able to do a full chroot into install & reinstall grub & kernel from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turned out that the kernel was missing. So I had to reinstall it. What I did was:

- booting via live usb and in the command line:

  ```
  mkdir /recovery
  mount -t ext4 /dev/sda6 /recovery
  mount -o bind /dev /recovery/dev
  mount -o bind /sys /recovery/sys
  mount -t proc none /recovery/proc

  chroot /recovery /bin/bash
  apt-get remove linux-image-4.19.0-9-amd64
  ```

At this point I had some problems because I had no internet connection in chrooted system and I couldn't do "apt-get install linux-image-4.19.0-9-amd64" so I downloaded manually linux-image-4.19.0-9-amd64.deb in live usb and then mounted it inside /recovery directory.

```
dpkg -i /recovery/download/linux-image-4.19.0-9-amd64.deb
update-grub
```

Then the grub menu was fixed and I could easily boot into the system, but it occured that /home partition was gone from fstab I could get into user account, so once again I booted via live usb and added appropriate line in fstab.

Now, system works fine apart from the fact that starting process takes a bit longer than it used to, but I can live with that.